# $q^{-\epsilon s/2} Z(V/\mathbb{F}_q; q^{-s})$ invariant under $s \mapsto N - s$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

> **Weil Conjectures.** Let $V/\mathbb{F}_q$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $N$.
>
> (b) **Functional Equation.** There is an integer $\epsilon$, called the Euler characteristic of $V$, such that$$Z(V/\mathbb{F}_q; 1/q^NT) = \pm q^{N\epsilon/2}T^\epsilon Z(V/\mathbb{F}_q; T).$$

**Question.** Let $V/\mathbb{F}_q$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $N$ defined over a finite field, and let $\epsilon$ be the Euler characteristic of $V$, as described above. How do I see that up to $\pm1$, the function$$q^{-\epsilon s/2} Z(V/\mathbb{F}_q; q^{-s})$$is invariant under the substitution $s \mapsto N - s$?

Comment: Are you really asking for a proof the functional equation?  Do you know the history of the proof of the Weil conjectures? If not, you can read a bit about it in one of the appendices of *Hartshorne*.  The proof of the functional equation depend on Poincare duality in etale cohomology.  Do you have sufficient background to follow a more detailed explanation along those lines?

Comment: @tracing Yes I think so with respect to background, I'll give the portion in Hartshorne you mentioned a look.